# Eigen RowVector out of scope produces "Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable X was corrupted"

Tags: c++, visual-studio, exception, eigen

I'm using Eigen library and get this very strange exception:

> Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'myVariableCopy' was corrupted.

It's from the following code:

```
void get_new_handle_locations()
{
    int count = 0;
    for (long vi = 0; vi < V.rows(); ++vi)
    {
        if (handle_id[vi] >= 0)
        {
            Eigen::RowVector3f myVariable = V.row(vi).cast<float>();

            if (handle_id[vi] == moving_handle)
            {
                Eigen::RowVector3f myVariableCopy = myVariable;
                myVariable -= handle_centroids.row(moving_handle).cast<float>();
                igl::rotate_by_quat(myVariable.data(), rotation.data(), myVariableCopy.data());
                myVariable = myVariableCopy;
                myVariable += handle_centroids.row(moving_handle).cast<float>();
            }

            handle_vertex_positions.row(count++) = myVariable.cast<double>();
        }
    }
} // This is where the exception is thrown
```

The exception is raised after the loop ends, and the condition doesn't pass for the last ~100 iterations so the variable should be out of scope for sure at this point

I'm using VS 2017.

I suppressed this exception but is there something I should worry about or is it a VS bug?

Comment: I highly suspect that this is happening because you write to `handle_vertex_positions.row(count++)` and `count` can just keep growing beyond the size of `handle_vertex_positions`.

Comment: I would not expect this to be a bug in Visual Studio. More likely you are corrupting the stack.

Comment: OK I think it's because `goalPositionCopy` is 3 dimensional and rotate_by_quat calls a function that uses it like it's 4 dimensional

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of the corruption is that `igl::rotate_by_quat` calls `igl::quat_mult` which expects `goalPositionCopy.data()` to have 4 dimensions, but it's declared as a 3-dimenional vector.

Comment: I am glad you have got your solution and thanks for your sharing, I would appreciate it if you mark them as answer and this will be beneficial to other community.

Comment: I can only accept this answer after 48 hours, and only 47 has passes